# R Shiny Download files from ahref tag created dynamically- Not Found error

Tags: r, shiny

Trying to create download links using anchor tags in Shiny. Depending on the number of files the links are created dynamically as below. But the error says file not found.

UI

```
uiOutput("result")
```

Server

```
  fileslist = strsplit(res,"#")[[1]]  #Sample data "output/file1#output/file2#output/file3"
  tags <- tagList("Files:")
  for (filepath in fileslist){
    tags <- tagList(tags, a("File", target="_blank", href=glue("{filepath}")))
  }
  output$result <- renderUI({
    tags
  })
```

It creates `a href` links successfully in the browser with url as below.

```
domain:1111/output/file1
domain:1111/output/file2
domain:1111/output/file3
```

But when clicked on the link i get `404 (Not Found)` error. And the files do exist in the directory.

App dir structure

```
  AppDir-
      ui.R
      server.R
      output-
           file1
           file2
           file3
```

The directory has all read permissions given.

Comment: hi, can you share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of what you've done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files are not served from the directory structure of your shiny project.
The simple way is to move your output folder to a www folder that is automatically made available for your application by shiny.

```
  AppDir-
      ui.R
      server.R
      www -
         output-
            file1
            file2
            file3
```

Then your href should work using `domain:1111/output/file1` (yes no www, only the content of it is shared)

You could also put in www other files such as pictures for your pages, CSS files or even javascript files

---

That said, www is not meant to be a writable folder. The better way is to have a separate writable folder (for example the one you already have `output`) and make it available to your application.

For this you can use the `addResourcePath()` function of Shiny

```
addResourcePath("output","./output")
```

and the files will be available through your href `domain:1111/output/file1`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for both the solutions. It worked perfectly

Comment: `addResourcePath` there is an extra `s`